# Placing a dash for each identical word (regex, php)

Tags: php, regex

Please tell me if it is possible to make a search for all identical words through rejax and insert a dash between them until such a word is no longer the next in the sentence.

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/1GQiQ8/2

My regex:

```
(\blong\b|\banyword\b)(-| )(\blong\b|\banyword\b)
```

Sample text:

```
test text long long test text
test text long long long long long long test text
test text long long test test long long long test text
```

How it should be:

```
test text long-long-long-long-long-long test text
test text long-long test test long-long-long test text
```

How does it work now:

```
test text long-long test text
test text long-long long-long long-long test text
test text long-long test test long-long long test text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
\b(long|anyword)\b\K[- ](?=(?:(?1))\b)
```

Replace with `-`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b1LMrg/1).

**If the words must be identical** use `\1` instead of `(?1)`:

```php
\b(long|anyword)\b\K[- ](?=\1\b)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b1LMrg/3)

**Details**

- `\b(long|anyword)\b` - Group 1: either of two words, as a whole word
- `\K` - match reset operator, it removes all text matched so far from the  match memory buffer
- `[- ]` - either a hyphen or space
- `(?=(?:(?1))\b)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with a whole `long` or `anyword` word.
- `(?=\1\b)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with the string captured in Group 1 as  a whole word.

Comment: @Cruglk I suggest using it with `preg_replace`: `preg_replace('~\b(long|anyword)\b\K[- ](?=(?:(?1))\b)~u', '-', $string)`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `foreach()` loop will do the job as well:

```
<?php

$string = 'test text long long test text';

$array = explode(' ',$string);

$finalString = '';
foreach($array as $key=> $arr){
    if($key ==0){
        $finalString = $arr;
    }else{
        if($arr == $array[$key-1]){
            $finalString .='-'.$arr;
        }else{
             $finalString .=' '.$arr;
        }
        
    }
    
}
echo $finalString;
```

Output:https://3v4l.org/FVSRU   And https://3v4l.org/jso3U

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Now my code works with the mb_ereg_replace function - but I will also find a use for your example.